# @Ignore tag on SpecFlow 2.0.0 results in build error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, specflow, nunit-3.0

I've recently upgraded from SpecFlow 1.9.0 to 2.0.0 and NUnit 2.6.4 to 3.2.1.

The SpecFlow feature file snippet below used to work before, however it's failing with this error now: **'NUnit.Framework.IgnoreAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments**

```
@Register @Ignore
Feature: Registration page
```

This is the auto-generated SpecFlow feature class snippet that's failing:
`[NUnit.Framework.IgnoreAttribute()]`

How can @Ignore tags be used in SpecFlow 2.0.0 and NUnit 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the tag has changed in the most recent version. Now you have to give it a reason ...

```
@Register @Ignore("reason")
Feature: Registration page
```

Comment: Thanks Xena, but unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. This is what I get in the generated file... `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "2.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute()]
    [NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("Registration page")]
    [NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("Register")]
    [NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("Ignore(\"reason")]
    [NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("for")]
    [NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("ignore\")")]`

Comment: You're right, it seems like you can only have one word. @Ignore("reason") works for me.

Comment: @DavidCamilleri please raise an issue for this at the github page.

Comment: @SamHolder It's a continuation on this issue - https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/517

Comment: @DavidCamilleri the implication in that thread is that it is fixed, but it seesm only fixed for single word reasons

Comment: I've added something to that thread to indicate that multi word reasons cause an issue

Comment: @SamHolder It won't work for me, even with a single word. `[NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("Ignore(\"reason\")")]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate the code-behind files of the feature files.
Then the IgnoreAttribute is generated with the correct parameters.

Comment: I regenerated the classes behind the feature files but it didn't help. Still getting this in the generated class... `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "2.0.0.0")]  [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]  [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute()]  [NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("Registration page")]  [NUnit.Framework.IgnoreAttribute()]  [NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("Register")]`

Comment: Could you post somewhere the package.config of your testproject?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>`